# assign language to user on registration in meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a problem with saving current language in new field for new registration in meteor.
Currently i'm using [tap-i18n](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n#tapi18n-api). I need get currently language tag and save it as user default language. Here is my code:

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if(!options.profile){
    options.profile = {};
  }
  options.profile.language = TAPi18n.getLanguage();
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

Am I doing something wrong with trying to override provided package behaviour?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is this code running on server side?

Comment: @iAmME Yes it is running on server side. In console i got: default prevented! AND Error: Internal server error [500]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way because `TAPi18n.getLanguage()` is only available on the client side and not on the server side. 
See: https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n